# Хранение цифровых и буквенных значений

Tags: mysql

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите, как быть в следующей ситуации: изначально в поле таблица mysql хранились только цифровые значения (`mediumint`). Теперь же нужно хранить ещё и буквенно-цифровые сочетания типа "ww1, ww2 и др". Но если изменить `mediumint` на `varchar`, то 5 будет больше 2000 при запросе `max()` к бд. Как быть?

Comment: а какие требования у вас к этому полю?

Comment: Запросы. Получить максимальное значение, например, среди всех цифр (без букв). Значения с буквами отмечаются единицей в другом поле, потому их можно отсечь. Остаются только цифры. Но т.к. поле varchar, то max() вернёт 5, a не 2000

Comment: храните буквы отдельно. в другом поле.

Comment: `MAX(0 + field)`. Но вообще лучше бы *в другом поле* не единицу рисовать, которая ниачём, а то самое `varchar`, оставив `mediumint`-поле без изменения, а вместо буквосодержащих значений помещать туда Null. Или, если версия сервера позволяет, использовать генерируемое поле.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman не будете оформлять ответ?

Comment: @n.osennij могу оформить, если вас он устраивает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в таблицу еще одно поле и храните там буквы, а поле с цифрами оставьте без изменений.

Comment: А стоит ли там хранить буквы - в этом отдельном поле? Или же стоит вывести буквы в отдельную таблицу, а в целевом поле указывать цифровой идентификатор?

Comment: это зависит от того как вы это будете использовать и от объема данных